# How can i call stack navigator from class component?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Im trying to create a expandable list with buttons inside to navigate other screens. I couldn't manage to call my stack navigator to navigate related screens. how can i get the props of App.js? because right now props holds my CONTENT table. or is there any better approach i can do? On the CONTENT, the id part is holds screen names on the stack navigator.

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, View, Image, Text, ImageBackground, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity, LayoutAnimation, UIManager, Platform, ScrollView} from "react-native";
    import { widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
    import { RFPercentage } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";
    
    class ExpandableItemComponent extends Component  {
        //Custom Component for the Expandable List
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                layoutHeight: 0,
            };
        }
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            if (nextProps.item.isExpanded) {
                this.setState(() => {
                    return {
                        layoutHeight: null,
                    };
                });
            } else {
                this.setState(() => {
                    return {
                        layoutHeight: 0,
                    };
                });
            }
        }
        shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
            if (this.state.layoutHeight !== nextState.layoutHeight) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
                <View>
                    {/*Header of the Expandable List Item*/}
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        activeOpacity={0.8}
                        onPress={this.props.onClickFunction}
                        style={styles.header}>
                        <Text style={styles.headerText}>{this.props.item.category_name}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <View
                        style={{
                            height: this.state.layoutHeight,
                            overflow: 'hidden',
                        }}>
                        {/*Content under the header of the Expandable List Item*/}
                        {this.props.item.subcategory.map((item, key, navigation) => (
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                key={key}
                                style={styles.content}
                                onPress={() =>  navigation.navigate(item.id)}>
                                <Text style={styles.text}>
                                    {item.val}
                                </Text>
                                <View style={styles.separator} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        ))}
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
    
    
    export default class BirNefesHuzurScreen extends Component{
    
        constructor() {
            super();
            if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
            }
            this.state = { listDataSource: CONTENT };
        }
        updateLayout = index => {
            LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
            const array = [...this.state.listDataSource];
            array[index]['isExpanded'] = !array[index]['isExpanded'];
            this.setState(() => {
                return {
                    listDataSource: array,
                };
            });
        };
        render(props) {
    
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <ScrollView>
                    <StatusBar hidden />
                    <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                        <ImageBackground
                            source={require("../../assets/BirNefesHuzur.png")}
                            resizeMode="cover"
                            style={styles.background}
                        >
                        </ImageBackground>
                    </View>
                    <Text style={styles.textContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>BİR NEFES HUZUR {"\n"}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Coğrafya kaderse, huzur da Çanakkale’nin kaderidir. Rüzgârı meşhurdur, doğası huzur verir. Çanakkale’de zirveden kıyılara, çam ağaçlarından makiye dönen bir bitki örtüsü hakimdir. Yazı cıvıl cıvıl, kışı yemyeşildir. Ormanları doğa tutkunlarını kucaklarken, kıyıları denize nazır keyif yapmayı sevenler için biçilmiş kaftandır. Çanakkale’de bir nefeste iki kıta, iki iklim tadarsınız. </Text>
                    </Text>
                        {this.state.listDataSource.map((item, key) => (
                            <ExpandableItemComponent
                                key={item.category_name}
                                onClickFunction={this.updateLayout.bind(this, key, props)}
                                item={item}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
    
            );
        }
    };
    
    const CONTENT = [
        {
            isExpanded: false,
            category_name: 'ÇANAKKALE MERKEZ',
            subcategory: [
                { id: 'DardanosHalkPlaji', val: 'Dardanos Halk Plajı' },
                { id: 'GuzelYaliPlaji', val: 'Güzelyalı Halk  Plajı' },
                { id: 'YeniKordonBarisPlaji', val: 'Yeni Kordon Barış Plajı' },
                { id: 'KepezBelediyesiHalkPlaji', val: 'Kepez Belediyesi Halk Plajı' },
                { id: 'KemerdereSuKemeri', val: 'Kemerdere Su Kemeri' }],
        },
        {
            isExpanded: false,
            category_name: 'AYVACIK',
            subcategory: [
                { id: 'KazDaglari', val: 'Kaz Dağları Milli Parkı' },
                { id: 'AdatepeKoyu', val: 'Adatepe Köyü' },
                { id: 'Babakale', val: 'Babakale' },
                { id: 'KadirgaKoyu', val: 'Kadırga Koyu' },
                { id: 'AssosYesilLiman', val: 'Assos Yeşil Liman' },
                { id: 'KoruobaKoyu', val: 'Koruoba Koyu' },
                { id: 'SivriceKoyu', val: 'Sivrice Koyu' },
                { id: 'SokakagiziKoyu', val: 'Sokakağzı Koyu' },
                { id: 'BabakaleAkliman', val: 'Babakale Akliman Koyu' }],
        },
        {
            isExpanded: false,
            category_name: 'BAYRAMİÇ',
            subcategory: [{ id: 'AyazmaPinariTabiatParki', val: 'Ayazma Pınarı Tabiat Parkı' }],
        },
        {
            isExpanded: false,
            category_name: 'BİGA',
            subcategory: [
                { id: 'Karabiga', val: 'Karabiga' },
                { id: 'UzunderePlaji', val: 'Uzundere Plajı' },
                { id: 'KemerKoyuSahili', val: 'Kemerköyü Sahili' },
                { id: 'SahmelekKoyu', val: 'Şahmelek Koyu' }],
        },
        {
            isExpanded: false,
            category_name: 'BOZCAADA',
            subcategory: [
                { id: 'PolenteFeneriVeRuzgarGulleri', val: 'Polente Feneri ve Rüzgar Gülleri' },
    
                { id: 'BozcaadaMerkeziPlaji', val: 'Bozcaada Merkezi Plajı' },
                { id: 'AyazmaPlaji', val: 'Ayazma Plajı' },
                { id: 'SuluBahceKoyu', val: 'Sulu Bahçe Koyu' },
                { id: 'HabbeliPlaji', val: 'Habbeli Plajı' },
                { id: 'AkvaryumKoyuMermerBurnu', val: 'Akvaryum Koyu (Mermer Burnu)' },
                { id: 'TuzburnuKoyu', val: 'Tuzburnu Koyu' },
                { id: 'BeylikKoyu', val: 'Beylik Koyu' },
                { id: 'PoyrazLimani', val: 'Poyraz Limanı' },
                { id: 'CayirKoyu', val: 'Çayır Koyu' }],
        },
        {
            isExpanded: false,
            category_name: 'ECEABAT',
            subcategory: [
                { id: 'AriburnuYarlariVeYukseksirt', val: 'Arıburnu Yarları ve Yükseksırt' },
                { id: 'KabatepeOrmanKamp', val: 'Kabatepe Orman Kamp' },
                { id: 'KucukAnafartalarKoyuSahili', val: 'Küçük Anafartalar Köyü Sahili' },
                { id: 'KucukKemikliBurnu', val: 'Küçük Kemikli Burnu' },
                { id: 'SulvaKoyu', val: 'Suvla Koyu' },
                { id: 'BuyukKemikliBurnu', val: 'Büyük Kemikli Burnu' }],
        },
        {
            isExpanded: false,
            category_name: 'EZİNE',
            subcategory: [{ id: 'Geyikli', val: 'Geyikli' },
            { id: 'YenikoyPapazPlaji', val: 'Yeniköy Papaz Plajı' }],
        },
        {
            isExpanded: false,
            category_name: 'GELİBOLU',
            subcategory: [{ id: 'SarozKorfeziKiyilari', val: 'Saroz Körfezi Kıyıları ' }],
        },
        {
            isExpanded: false,
            category_name: 'GÖKÇEADA',
            subcategory: [{ id: 'GokceadadaDenizeGirilecekYerler', val: 'Gökçeada’da Denize Girilecek Yerler' },
            { id: 'EskiRumKoyleri', val: 'Eski Rum Köyleri' },
            { id: 'GokceadaSualtiMilliParki', val: 'Gökçeada Sualtı Milli Parkı' }],
        },
        {
            isExpanded: false,
            category_name: 'YENİCE',
            subcategory: [{ id: 'KazDaglariYeniceOrmanlari', val: 'Kaz Dağları - Yenice Ormanları' }],
        },
    ];
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to add props as an argument in the constructor.

Comment: oh god haha   im gonna try it now thnaks a lot i think its just escape from my notice  thank's gonna do it now